# Assignment operator overload : Error Handling scenario

Tags: c++, string

Please refer below program before answering question. Explained the code in comments.

So my question here is in assignment operator overloading how to handle the case where new() failed to allocate memory.

For example `Obj1` is holding string `"GeeksQuiz"`. Assigning `Obj2` to `Obj1`. During assigning (in assignment operator overload function) first we free `Obj1` and then recreate `Obj1` with `Obj2` values. So in the case where `new` fails to allocate memory how to retain old `Obj1` values? Since we freed `Obj1` values in starting of function.

All that I want is to have the old values for `Obj1` when the assigning operation fails.

Please help me in this. I want perfect code, without any memory leaks covering all scenarios. Thanks in Advance

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstring>
using namespace std;

class String
{
private:
    char *string_data;
    int size;
public:
    String(const char *str = NULL); // constructor
    ~String() { delete [] string_data;  }// destructor
    void print() { cout << string_data << endl; } // Function to print string
    String& operator = (const String &); // assignment operator overload
};

String::String(const char *str)  // Constructor
{
    size = strlen(str);
    string_data = new char[size+1];
    if (string_data != NULL)
        strcpy(string_data, str);
    else
        cout<<"compiler failed to allocate new memory";
}

String& String::operator = (const String &str) // assignment operator overload
{
    if(this != &str) 
    {
        delete [] string_data; // Deleting old data and assigning new data below
        size = str.size;
        string_data = new char[size+1];
        if(string_data != NULL) // This condition is for cheking new memory is success 
            strcpy(string_data, str.string_data);
        else
            cout<<"compiler failed to allocate new memory"; // My quetsion comes in this scenario...
    }
    return *this;
}

int main()
{
    String Obj1("GeeksQuiz");
    String Obj2("stackoverflow");

    Obj1.print(); // Printing Before assigment
    Obj2.print();

    Obj1 = Obj2;  // Assignment is done. 

    Obj1.print(); // Printing After assigment
    Obj2.print();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Allocate first, then if it's all good delete old data.

Comment: the `if` path in your assignment operator doesn't return anything.

Comment: Why on earth do you think you can - just for fun (or practice?) - implement a robust string class? If you want to program in C++, learn to use its standard library!

Comment: @ Wolf : I also have same doubt like you. But it was asked during one of my interviews. Thank u

Comment: I see, my sympathy! (Strange interviewers! Rocket science?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, implementing a robust string is difficult, unless you want to do it for learning purposes always use `std::string`.

Then take into account that [operator new](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_new) always returns non-null pointers (unless you are also implementing a non standard custom `new` operator), instead it throws a `std::bad_alloc` exception if it fails to allocate the data. If you want to handle the allocation fail case you need to add a try-catch block

```
char *data = NULL;
try {
  data = new char[str.size + 1];
} catch (std::bad_alloc &e) {
  std::cout << "Allocation failed: " << e.what() << std::endl;
  throw; // <- You probably want to rethrow the exception.
}
strcpy(data, str.string_data);
delete [] string_data;
string_data = data;
size = str.size;
```

The important part is to leave your class in a consistent state when the exception is thrown, that's why you must first allocate the new data and then if it succeeds, delete the old data. However bad_alloc exceptions are rarely handled at class level, commonly you let the exception be thrown (that's why I rethrow in the code sample) and let the client code handle that.

If you really want your code to be exception proof I would advice the use of smart pointers, and as already said, in this case use `std::string`.

Comment: I'd stress the importance of using `std::string` first, than (if at all) talk about handling `std::bad_alloc`

Comment: @Wolf, agree. Changed that.

Answer (score 2):

Temporary or dummy variables.

Allocate new memory, assign pointer to a temporary variable. If it succeeds *then* free the old memory and reassign that pointer variable.

---

Pseudo-ish code:

```
char *temp = new char[new_size];
std::copy(new_data, new_data + new_size, temp);
delete [] old_data;
old_data = temp;
old_size = new_size;
```

Comment: can you please add corrected code for that function

Comment: Your *Pseudo-ish code* looks very incorrect. Intentionally?

Comment: @Wolf Why would you say that? If those variables were defined it's actually four fully valid statements.

Comment: `old_data` **looks like** it's the data source, I know it represents the `string_data` part of the question.

Comment: Much better, whereas I think it still looks quite odd because the mixing of new-style and old-style code...

Answer (score 0):

1st allocate memory in a temporary variable, if it's successful then only delete old value.

Comment: String& String::operator = (const String &str) // assignment operator overload
{
    if(this != &str) // self assignment check
    {
        int temp_int = str.size;
        char *temp_string = new char[size+1];
        strcpy(temp_string, str.string_data);
        if(string_data != NULL) // This condition is for cheking new memory is success 
        {
            size = temp_int;
            delete [] string_data;
            strcpy(string_data, temp_string);
        }
        else
            cout<<"compiler failed to allocate new memory"; 
    }
    return *this;
}

Comment: i am weak in pointer string copy stuff. Cna you please check and corect me

Comment: String& String::operator = (const String &str) // assignment operator overload
{
    if(this != &str) 
    {
        size = str.size;
        char* string_data_temp = new char[size+1];
        if(string_data_temp != NULL) // This condition is for cheking new memory is success 
  {
   delete [] string_data; // Delete now 
   string_data = string_data_temp;
            strcpy(string_data, str.string_data);
  }
        else
            cout<<"compiler failed to allocate new memory"; // My quetsion comes in this scenario...
    }
    return *this;
}